# how to add xenial versions of package into bionic?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, 18.04

I need some versions of a package which are in xenial's repo, but I have bionic.
How can I do?

The long version is : I need libopencv in version 2.4 (which is provided by the xenial official repository) but in bionic it is in version 3. 
so I need to remove version 3, add the xenial repository, and use apt-get specifying version 2.4.
Is it safe? How to do this?

thank you

EDIT:
What I am trying to do is to install sikuli, an applications driver which works by picture recognition. It needs among other dependencies, opencv (for the 'vision' ability) but in version 2.4.

Comment: It is impossible without crashing your system.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe it better to solve this with virtualenv or docker or a vm ?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but Ubuntu Bionic has package named [*sikulix*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/sikulix), and [it depends on OpenCV](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/sikulix). Will this solve your problem?